# Eclipse. Keyboard shortcut to close search window

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Does any one know what is the keyboard shortcut to close the search window that shows up on  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to close the find window. You might be able to change the keybindning in Window > Preferences > General > Key. I had a quick fly-over but didn't find anything useful.